# Can't install dependencies correctly on ReasonML project setup

Tags: ocaml, opam, reason

I'm new to ReasonML and I'm starting to learn it. I'm trying to setup a new ReasonML project using the [ReasonNativeProject](https://github.com/reasonml/ReasonNativeProject) repository. When I run the step to install the dependencies with opam using `opam pin add -y ReasonNativeProject .` I get the following message saying it couldn't install reason properly.

```
ReasonNativeProject needs to be installed.
The following dependencies couldn't be met:
  - ReasonNativeProject -> reason = 1.13.3
Your request can't be satisfied:
  - reason.1.13.3 is not available because the package is pinned to https://github.com/facebook/reason.git#0.0.6, version 0.0.5.

No solution found, exiting
[NOTE] Pinning command successful, but your installed packages may be out of sync.
```

Without all the dependencies installed properly I won't be able to build my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This repository requires `reason = 1.13.3`, but you added a pin forcing opam to get `reason` from a tag in its git repo (which corresponds to a fixed older version).

You can `opam pin remove reason` (and `opam update` after) to remove this pin and pick the latest version from opam.